# Community Promotion Ads — 2019

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2019 is here! And with the new year, as usual, comes a new iteration of **Community Promotion Ads**! Let’s refresh these for the coming year :)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- artistic blogs and websites
- useful resources and tutorials for designers of all skill levels
- examples of well-designed content
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3573).

Comment: WHAT HAVE YOU DONE WITH GRACE NOTE? AHHHHHHH

Comment: I'll post a pic with today's paper later. More on the ransom later ;)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Upvoting answers is like spreading love]

Comment: Sadly this is no longer the upvote button, so the disconnect may be confusing to some people

Answer (score 4):

[image: Accepting an answer is like the ultimate pat on the back]

Comment: I personally don't like the gradient in this one. Also, that's no longer the accept icon `(-_-)`

Comment: Oh really? I didn't even know. Since I have no open questions, I can't really refer to the new icon. Got a link?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Reviewing is like helping a grandma cross the road]

Comment: Really? A downvote with no comment whatsoever? What has this site become?

Comment: For meta that's not uncommon. But I just downvoted because there are very few users who actually review, so this ad is pretty useless IMO

Comment: Isn't that a reason to _have_ an ad, so more users become aware there is such a thing as reviewing?

Comment: @PieBie does not really matter, most users have so low reputation thet they cant really review anyway. Anyway stackexcahnge has hidden the review for a reason (possibly bad one but has), so its not really our job to try to fix their bad gui.

Comment: So our community does not deem quality reviews important. OK, got it.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Visiting our chatroom is like dropping by good friends]

Comment: The combination of the GD logo and speech bubble in this one looks weird to me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Help this community grow -- follow us on twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting